# Conda package finds conflicts on newly created env and fails to show them

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, menpo

I tried to install `menpodetect` after creating a new env in Anaconda

```
conda create --name detector
conda activate detector
conda install -c menpo menpodetect
```

Anaconda cloud: https://anaconda.org/menpo/menpodetect

This is the output of `conda install -c menpo menpodetect`

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.\
failed

UnsatisfiableError:
```

`python --version` -> `Python 3.7.4`

`conda list` is empty (since the env has just been created)

What's wrong?

EDIT --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

`conda install -c conda-forge menpodetect` returns

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - menpodetect

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menpodetect team has dropped support for windows and [does not plan to reintroduce it](https://github.com/menpo/menpodetect/issues/16). The only version still available for windows is the 3 year old 0.5 version, as you can see on the anaconda [website](https://anaconda.org/menpo/menpodetect).

With a package that old, it can happen that not all dependencies are still available from the default channels. You can however still install it, if you use the [free channel](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/free-channel.html), which contains packages prior to September 2017. It was removed from `conda` defaults with 4.7.

Use:

```
conda install -c free -c menpo menpodetect
```

Depending on your usecase however, it might be preferable to switch to Linux or OSX to be able to install the latest version using James suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it from the `conda-forge` channel.  The author started migrating to that channel about a year ago.

```
conda install -c conda-forge menpodetect
```

Comment: Unfortunately menpodetect is not available in conda-forge. I updated the question with the output.

Comment: Ah, are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes I didn't realize it would make a difference. So is it available on linux?

Comment: @zcb linux and OSX are officially supported. See [the github](https://github.com/menpo/menpodetect) and also the page on [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/menpodetect)